# Scrolling through mouse dragging in qt

Tags: c++, qt, scroll, mouseevent

I am working in c++ on qt 5.10.1, and I have a widget into which I dynamically create additional widgets.

```
for(QString pics : nameVector) 
    {
        QIcon* buttonIcon = new QIcon;

        QImage image(QString("%1").arg(pics));  //QImage's Constructor takes a file path
        image.scaled(9000, scrollerHeight*7 , Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);

        QPixmap pixMap(QPixmap::fromImage(image).scaled(5000, scrollerHeight, Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation)); //8 will do it once scrollbar is removed.;
        buttonIcon->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image).scaled(5000, scrollerHeight * m_scaleFactor, Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation));

        QPushButton *pixButton = new QPushButton;

        pixButton->setIconSize(imageSize);
        pixButton->setIcon(*buttonIcon);
        pixButton->setObjectName(pics + "button");
        ui.horizontalLayout_2->addWidget(pixButton); //addButton


        QObject::connect(&pixButton, &pixButton->clicked(true),
            &ui.tempOutputLabel, &fileFinder(pics);
        }
```

the scroll area in the widget gets larger horizontally with each new addition - this is done through qts "horizontal policy: expanding" in qt designer.

I now have a scroll bar, but what I want to be able to do, is move my mouse(preferably while holding the right mouse button) and pulling through the images - like scrolling on a phone.

I have started by adding mouse move and mouse button events

```
void JobPreviewWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)  //najdeme najblizsi obrazok
        ;
    if (event->button() == Qt::RightButton)
    {
        QPointF m_rightEnd = event->pos();
        m_offset += m_rightEnd - m_rightStart;
    }
}

void JobPreviewWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::RightButton)
    {
        m_rightStart = event->pos();
    }
}

void JobPreviewWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    m_mousePoint = event->pos();
    repaint(); //this is the problem for me
}
```

I do not know how to make the horizontal layout repaintable with the offset m_offset. Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: You might want to look at [`QScroller`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscroller.html).

Comment: QScroller seems to be what I am looking for. Will look into it more when I'm back at work.